# Proving the General Case of this Quadratic Inequality?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose I have the following inequality:

$$\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2} \leq \min(S_1^2, S_2^2, \ldots, S_n^2)$$

Where:

- $N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $S_1^2, S_2^2, \ldots, S_n^2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$

**I am trying to prove whether this inequality is True or False for the general case**

I am not sure how to prove this for the general case - but I think I was able to show these for a specific case where $S_1 = S_2 = \cdots = S_n = S$.

- Suppose we define $W_i = \frac{N_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n N_j}$
- It then follows that $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i = 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2 \leq 1$
- This means we can re-write the inequality as $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2S_i^2 \leq \min(S_1^2, S_2^2, \ldots, S_n^2)$
- Since $S_1 = S_2 = \cdots = S_n = S$ , then $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2S_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2S^2 $
- This means that we can again re-write the inequality as  $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2S^2 \leq \min(S^2) = S^2$
- Re-writing the above step, we have: $S^2\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2 \leq S^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2  \leq 1$
- As a result, I think the inequality has been proven for a specific case when $S_1 = S_2 = \cdots = S_n = S$.

**My Question:** However, I am still interested in learning if this inequality can be proven (yes or no) for the **general case** where $S_1^2 \neq S_2^2 \neq \cdots \neq S_n^2$

Can someone please show me how to do this? Is the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality needed for this?

Thanks!

Comment: This *cannot* be true in the general case, because with increasing (e.g.) $S_1$ the left-hand side becomes arbitrarily large, whereas the right-hand side does not change.

Comment: If all $S_i$ are equal then the inequality is $N_1^2 + \cdots + N_n^2\le (N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2$, which is true and follows (e.g.) from expanding the right-hand side.

Comment: The best bound you can get for the left side (in general)  is $\max \{S_1^{2},S_2^{2},...,S_n^{2}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The inequality in question does not generally hold. However, the following does$$\max_{\{N_i\}_{i=1}^N}\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2}\le\max\{S_1^2,\cdots ,S_n^2\},$$which we will prove.**

WLOG, we assume $S_1^2\le S_2^2\le\cdots \le S_n^2$. We try to maximize the LHS of the inequality w.r.t. $N_i$s. Hence,
$$
\max_{\{N_i\}_{i=1}^N}\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_N)^2}
{
=
\max_{M\ge n}\max_{\{N_i\}_{i=1}^n,\sum_{i=1}^nN_i=M}\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2}
\\=
\max_{M\ge n}\max_{\{N_i\}_{i=1}^n,\sum_{i=1}^nN_i=M}\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{M^2}
\\=
\max_{M\ge n}\frac{(M-n+1)^2S_n^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}S_i^2}{M^2}
\\=
S_n^2\cdot\max_{M\ge n}\frac{(M-n+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{S_n^2}}{M^2}.
}
$$
The function $f(x)=\frac{(x-a)^2+b}{x^2}$ has a minimum over $(0,\infty)$ at $x=a+b/a$. Applying this fact to $f(M)=\frac{(M-n+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{S_n^2}}{M^2}$, we have $a=n-1$ and $b=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{S_n^2}$ and the minimum resides in
$$
M^*=n-1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{(n-1)S_n^2}.
$$
It is easy to observe that $n-1\le M^*\le n$. Therefore, $\frac{(M-n+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{S_n^2}}{M^2}$ is strictly increasing for $M\ge n$. Therefore,
$$
\max_{M\ge n}\frac{(M-n+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{S_n^2}}{M^2}=\lim_{M\to\infty} \frac{(M-n+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{S_i^2}{S_n^2}}{M^2}=1.
$$

> We finally conclude
> $$
> \max_{\{N_i\}_{i=1}^N}\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2}\le\max\{S_1^2,\cdots ,S_n^2\}.
> $$

Comment: Should it be $(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2$ in the denominator on the left? In that case a simple proof would be $$
\frac{N_1^2S_1^2 + N_2^2S_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2S_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2} \leq \frac{N_1^2 + N_2^2 + \cdots + N_n^2}{(N_1 + N_2 + \cdots + N_n)^2} \cdot \max S_i^2 \le \max S_i^2
$$ since $N_1^2 + \cdots + N_n^2\le (N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2$.

Comment: Yes. This proof for the modified inequality is remarkably simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality cannot be true in the general case, because with increasing (e.g.) $S_1$ the left-hand side becomes arbitrarily large, whereas the right-hand side does not change.

If all $S_j = S$ are equal then

$$
\frac{N_1^2 S_1^2 + \cdots + N_n^2 S_n^2}{(N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2} = 
\frac{N_1^2  + \cdots + N_n^2 }{(N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2} \cdot S^2 \le S^2
$$
because
$$
N_1^2  + \cdots + N_n^2 \le (N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2
$$
as can be seen by expanding the right-hand side.

An upper bound for the general case is obtained in a similar way:
$$
\frac{N_1^2 S_1^2 + \cdots + N_n^2 S_n^2}{(N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2} \le 
\frac{N_1^2  + \cdots + N_n^2 }{(N_1 + \cdots + N_n)^2} \cdot \max(S_1^2, \ldots, S_n^2) \le \max(S_1^2, \ldots, S_n^2)  \, .
$$

Comment: Congratulations on 100k, I believe that’s recent

Comment: @FShrike: Thank you.